# Oracle Between return is not expected

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a varchar colunm. with content

```
ColumnX
________
ABC
DEF
1
2
3
4
40
50
```

I need to get number between 1 and 4. SO i have this SQL

```
SELECT columnX 
FROM table 
WHERE regexp_substr(columnX, '[[:digit:]]') BETWEEN 1 and 4;
```

But my result i get is 1,2,3,4 and 40.
What shall I do to get it right?

Comment: Looks like the regex is only checking the first character or the column, could you not expand it to make sure it only checks 1 character (i.e. doesn't match items with more than 1)?

Comment: Yes, when I set between 1 and 5, I get additional 50 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a quantifier to match more than 1 character. In this case, I used the `+` quantifier, which matches one or more occurrences of the characters (digits, in this case).

Try this:

```
WITH
  test_data AS
  (SELECT 'ABC' AS columnX FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT '1' FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT '2' FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT '3' FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT '4' FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT '40' FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT '50' FROM dual
)
SELECT columnX
  FROM test_data
WHERE regexp_substr(columnX, '[[:digit:]]+') BETWEEN 1 AND 4;
```

Output:

```
COLUMNX
-------
1       
2       
3       
4
```

Comment: my problem is, the number can increase to as much as 100. I have to add in 100 lines?